# Motion sensor script

Tags: gpio, python

Hey guys I'm trying to create a script which counts the number of times a person has interacted with the motion sensor using a while loop, however whenever the motion sensor has been interacted it constantly counts even though i havent reinteracted with the sensor. Any reason why?

here is the code of the script :

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
PIR_PIN = 7
GPIO.setup(PIR_PIN, GPIO.IN)

def MOTION(PIR_PIN):
       count = 1
       while(GPIO.input(PIR_PIN) == GPIO.HIGH):
       print (“Attendees: ”, count)
       count = count + 1
print “PIR Module Test (CTRL+C to exit)”
time.sleep(2)
print “Ready”

try:
       GPIO.add_event_detect(PIR_PIN, GPIO.RISING, callback=MOTION)
       while 1:
                      time.sleep(100)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
       print “ Quit”
       GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Firstly your code looks invalid, inconsistent tabs. Secondly you should not have a while loop in your callback method.

Comment: how would i go about doing it? @CoderMike

Comment: In your callback method just increment a global counter. Get rid of the while loop.